Bootlooped phone due to lack of internal storage memory
Bootlooped phone due to lack of internal storage memory.
The phone is not rooted. Not a custom ROM.
USB debugging is disabled. adb is disabled.
Give me some solutions to have access to the internal memory, to transfer some files from the phone to the laptop to free up the memory.
or convert the memory card or usb flash drive into a part of the internal memory so that the system boots and comes up.
Phone files are important to me, I don't want them to be deleted.

I have two phones with this problem. The phone is a22 5g and s22 ultra

too late, you should have freed memory earlier. if the phone supports it - boot into recovery mode and select the "lacking storage booting" or "save mode" boot option

How to boot in recovery mode?

Based on the model numbers these devices look like Samsung devices. Thus they should have what Samsung calls Safe mode. Have you tried to boot into safe mode?

I pressed the buttons and it didn't go to safe mode.
